# processing between sequential executions

Tags: programming, qiskit, ibm-quantum-devices

Regarding real quantum computers of IBM, can one execute a circuit that contains measurements and afterwards get counts and then, based on the results of measurements (from counts), decide if to build circuit A or circuit B that will be executed on the same quantum register with `init_qubits=False` and with use of `rep_delay` parameter, so that the chosen circuit, A or B will run on the quantum register with output state of the first circuit?

Answer (score 2):

Currently (Feb 2021), no. The run/measure/condition/run loop needs to be handled on user-side and it is not possible to preserve the state of quantum register among runs.

However checkout the IBM Quantum Development Roadmap:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=154&v=bp7UFdtwdTw

Jay Gambetta explains that in 2021 IBM will launch the *Quantum Runtime*. By bringing together classical and quantum computation on the server-side you should be able to run a *Quantum Program* that contains a similar logic to the one you are describing. However, you are interested in continuing a computation without reseting the quantum registers.

In 3:32 of the same video, Jay describes *Dynamic Circuits*. That's much closer to what you are searching for. Circuit with branching in them. They are planned for 2022.

If you prefer reading over a video, here is the roadmap as a blog post: https://www.ibm.com/blogs/research/2021/02/quantum-development-roadmap/

If you are curious about how a *Quantum Program* might look like, check the OpenQASM3 specification draft: https://qiskit.github.io/openqasm/

**Update (Feb 2021):** In the direction towards dynamic circuit (and a positive answer to your question), today [is possible to do mid-circuit measurements in the IBMQ backends](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/research/2021/02/quantum-mid-circuit-measurement/).

Here, an example:

```
from qiskit import *

provider = IBMQ.load_account()
backend = provider.get_backend('ibmqx2')

circuit = QuantumCircuit(1,2)
circuit.h(0)
circuit.measure(0,0)
circuit.x(0)
circuit.measure(0,1)

display(circuit.draw('mpl'))

result = execute(circuit, backend).result()
visualization.plot_histogram(result.get_counts())
```

[image]

[image]

This allows you to continue the execution after measurement. Consider that the first measurement colapses the superposition to either 0 or 1. The X gate flips that first result and then it is saved in the second classical bit.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But it sounds like it can be done now, but as you wrote, on the user side? And I wonder, how it can be done.

Comment: because it is not possible to preserve the state of a quantum register among runs, it is not possible to do that on user-side. I updated the first paragraph to clarify that.

Comment: Thanks, but if I use init_qubits=False for the second circuit with a very small rep_delay parameter value, wouldn't it be possible to preserve the state? or that preserving state between executions is just completely impossible?

Comment: the user-server-user cycle is way too long relative to the decoherence time. Decoherence destroys everything. The challenge is to bring CPU/QPU very closely (as is planned in the roadmap for 2022) to be able to classically compute inside the decoherence window.